# What is mean soft delete integration?

Tags: php, soft-delete

As my client asked me to integrate soft delete on his web application. But I have never done this, please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?
Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="soft+delete"&oq="soft+delete"

Comment: "Soft delete" means you don't actually delete the data.  Instead, you include a flag on the data (perhaps a simple `IsDeleted` boolean value) which indicates if it should be visible to the application or not.  So the application essentially ignores "soft-deleted" data, but anybody with access to the database (for audit purposes, perhaps), or another application for some other purpose, can still see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A soft delete is when you mark a record as deleted instead of deleting the record from the table.

To implement this you need another field in the table, for example named `Deleted`. Use a bit/boolean field and set it to `0` or `false` (depending on what database you use) when you create the record (and on existing records).

To delete a record you just change the value in that field. Example:

```
update
  SomeTable
set
  Deleted = 1
where
  Id = @Id
```

Wherever you use that table you have to filter out the deleted records (unless they should actually be shown anyway). Example:

```
select
  SomeField
from
  SomeTable
where
  Deleted = 0
```

Comment: Thanks !. I have done it before , without knowing it's tech word